# Number Theory/ Proofs

Tags: number-theory

I need help with this proof, it is quite hard (this is all new to me) and I have only found basic proofs online. 
----> If x and y are rational numbers, then x + y is an integer.

A link to a similar proof or how to approach it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: 2) Is rather simple. Consider $m=4n>n$. 3) Is bogus. Chose $x=y=\frac13$ then $x+y = \frac23$ which is not an integer.

Comment: It says $n$ is an integer, which might be negative. So we can't say $k$ is positive. But we can say $n=km$ and therefore $|n|=|k|m$.

Comment: Perhaps it should be "if $x$ and $y$ are rational, so too is $x + y$ rational"?

Answer (score 0):

In first you cannot say $k \ge 1$ as $n$ is non zero not positive. Rather see that $m \le n$ is equivalent to saying $-n \le m \le n$ which obviously being a factor it has to.

3) does not make sense as take $x=1/2, y=1/3$, does $x+y \in \mathbb{Z}$??